# Why must I instantiate an Electron.BrowserWindow using "new BrowserWindow" instead of "new Electron.BrowserWindow"?

Tags: typescript, electron

The following code works:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

class Main {
    static mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;
    static application: Electron.App;

    private static onWindowAllClosed() 
    {
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
            Main.application.quit();
    }

    private static onClose()
    {
        Main.mainWindow = null;
    }

    private static onReady()
    {
        Main.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
        Main.mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
        Main.mainWindow.on('closed', Main.onClose);
    }

    static main(app: Electron.App)
    {
        Main.application = app;
        Main.application.on('window-all-closed', Main.onWindowAllClosed);
        Main.application.on('ready', Main.onReady);
    }
}

Main.main(app);
```

When I try (in onReady) to instead do:

```
Main.mainWindow = new Electron.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
```

I receive an error when running the application in Electron:

> Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: Electron is not defined

The code compiles fine when running "tsc".

Looking at the typing definitions, I saw that Electron.BrowserWindow is a class, while BrowserWindow (the one being destructured from importing the module) is defined under the CommonElectron interface as:

```
BrowserWindow: typeof Electron.BrowserWindow;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `electron` typings in DefinitelyTyped is outdated.

The `Electron` you refer to is the namespace created by the typings (type definition) to hold all types that described the types in `electron`.

In the actual JavaScript, `electron` does not have a global variable `Electron` defined (anymore), thus the error you see.

The import statement `import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron'` is the ES6 syntax to get the actual `BrowserWindow` class so you can use it.

I agree that having the typings exposing the namespace `Electron` is confusing and should be removed.

`electron` is working on having its own typings.

You can follow it here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4875